# Ant design drawer title to put div and space tag

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im using ant design **[drawer](https://3x.ant.design/components/drawer/)**  , I have some conflict 
i tried to add drawer title to space but not working , anyone know how to do that correctly ?

issue is

```
title={"My account no:" +   this.props.accountId}
```

here the conflict **My account no:123456**

i want to put some space with text and number like this **My account no:  123456**

Thanks

**coed here.**

```
 <Drawer
            title={"My account no:" +   this.props.accountId}
            width={720}
            onClose={this.onDrawerClose}
            maskClosable={false}
            visible={this.state.statusChangeDrawerVisible}
            bodyStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}>

          </Drawer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
title={"My account no: " +   this.props.accountId}
```

Keep space after ':' in "My account no: " just as above

Comment: checkout my codepan edit: 
https://codepen.io/hemu2253/pen/xxwyRVg
SInce change is space, it is quite difficult to recognise, but this works. I use a lot for my projects

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put space after colon, you also might sum the strings as you've just did it with `this.props.accountId` :

```
title={"My account no:" + " "  + this.props.accountId + " bla bla bla" }
```